# converting pyspark DataFrame to LabeledPoint without dropping to RDD

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to pyspark DataFrame, and this really bugs me somehow. Maybe I'm not understanding this correctly.

say that I have a data frame

```
a = sqlContext.createDataFrame([[(2,3,4)],[(1,2,3)]],['things'])
```

If I want to convert this to LabeledPoint, I need to drop down to RDD using map function.

```
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
def convert(x):
    z = [float(y) for y in x]
    return LabeledPoint(z[0], z[1:])

rdd = a.map(lambda x: convert(x['things']))
rdd.take(2)
df=rdd.toDF()
```

Why can't I use DataFrame select statement combined with UDF like below?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
def convert(x):
   z = [float(y) for y in x]
   return LabeledPoint(z[0], z[1:])

udf_convert = udf(convert)
df = a.select(udf_convert(a['things']))
display(df)
```

I'm getting an error that says:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 6 in stage 33.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 6.0 in stage 33.0 (TID 101, localhost): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your `udf` [definition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.functions.udf). The return value is not StringType (which is the default) so you need to specify it. Unfortunately there is no `LabeledPointUDT` so you cannot use `udf` for such operation.

Taking one step back, `LabeledPoint` is used with `mllib`, which works mainly with `RDD`. Why would you want to make `LabeledPoint` in a `DataFrame`? It will be awkward to use it later anyway.

If you choose to use `DataFrame` + `ml`, you'll be happy to find out that there is a `VectorUDT` (in `mllib.linalg` before Spark 2.0, in `ml.linalg` with 2.0) to help with your `udf` functions.

Comment: thank you. i'm not quite sure how UDF and UDT relate to one another. can you point me to appropriate sites for reference?

Comment: [User Defined Function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=udf#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) works with DataFrame columns. Currently in pyspark there is no official support for [User Defined Type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html).